# Know more about shared libraries of a executable file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shared-libraries, ldd

Is there a way to know what shared libraries are used from a executable file ?

From DivFix++ for example:

```
$ file DivFix++ 
DivFix++: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, stripped
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using ldd:

```
$ ldd DivFix++
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `ldd` command which prints the shared library dependencies:

```
ldd DivFix++
```